# Nested JSON to CSV conversion using Python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested JSON file that needs to convert to CSV.

I'm trying to convert by using Python pandas and json_normalize method.

But not able to get the expected output.This is my sample JSON file.

```
{"issues": [{"id": 520,"project": {"id": 2,"name": "Partner Training Program"},"custom_fields": [{"id": 4,"name": "Content Owner","value": "Sin Yong Chuah"},{"id": 19,"name": "Course Languages","multiple": true,"value": ["English","Chinese Traditional","Indonesian (MT)","Japanese","Korean","Thai (MT)","Vietnamese"]}]}]}
```

I'm looking for csv with below columns

```
issues_id, issues_project_id,issues_project_name,custom_fields_id,custom_fields_name,custom_fields_value
```

This is python code I used to convert

```
json_file=open(input_file_name).read()
jon_data=json.loads(json_file)
df=json_normalize(json_data['issues'])
df.to_csv(output_file_name,index=False)
```

Comment: Can you also share what you have tried so far and what is going wrong? Do you have code?

Comment: can you please beautify your json I am getting error

Comment: This is my sample json   {"issues": [{"id": 520,"project": {"id": 2,"name": "Partner Training Program"},"custom_fields": [{"id": 4,"name": "Content Owner","value": "Sin Yong Chuah"},{"id": 19,"name": "Course Languages","multiple": true,"value": ["English","Chinese Traditional","Indonesian (MT)","Japanese","Korean","Thai (MT)","Vietnamese"]}]}]}

Comment: Im trying to convert using below code   

json_file=open(input_file_name).read()
jon_data=json.loads(json_file)
df=json_normalize(json_data['issues'])
df.to_csv(output_file_name,index=False)

With the above code, my CSV file is having the only a column for the custom_feilds node. But my requirement is to get the 3 separate columns  i.e custom_filed_id, custom_feld_name, custiom_feild_value

Comment: Try using read_json https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html